# Splitting up a numbers in Python

Tags: python

how can i split up a number ? for example (10 should look like a 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

I'm a beginner so please don't go crazy with an answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

therefore you could simply use a for loop. 
which looks something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
x = 10
answer = np.arange(1,x+1)
```

Now answer is a numpy array of numbers going from 1 to 10.

Comment: Or without numpy: `list(range(1, x + 1))`

Comment: Why, for crying out loud, do you need `numpy` for this?! Just like saying: "First, install MATLAB. Then, simply use `linspace(1,10,10)`."

Comment: I solved his problem. Numpy is a standard python package. Sorry for trying to help a beginner.